# How to update column based on unique set of multiple column values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have below table. Here value1 is from tableA and value2 from tableB . I am trying to update value1 column with value2 column value. But if you see the After Fix data, it just took the first row value2 and updated other all rows with same value.

[image]

But I want something like this ...

[image]

My query is (using MSSQL) :

```
      WITH DataSet as (
   select  distinct tabA.id , tabB.MappId  
from AC_BORDRO_ALLOCATION_TRK tabB JOIN AC_INSTALLMENT ai ON tabB.INSTALLMENT_ID =ai.ID 
JOIN AC_CREDIT_ALLOCATION_IN_BORDRO_TRK cb ON tabB.ID =cb.BORDRO_ALLOCATION_ID  
JOIN AC_INSTALLMENT_TRK tabA ON ai.id=tabA.id
JOIN AC_INSTALLMENT bordro_installment ON tabB.MappId =bordro_installment.id  
JOIN AC_INSTALLMENT_STATUS ais on ai.LAST_INSTALLMENT_STATUS_ID  = ais.ID 
JOIN AC_ENTRY ae on ae.REFERENCE_ID  = tabB.MappId 
where bordro_installment.INSTALLMENT_STATUS = 3 and abs(tabB.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT) 
!= abs(tabA.PAID_AMOUNT_IN_BODRO)  
and tabB.REMAINING_AMOUNT_TO_BE_PAID  = 0 and tabB .REFUND_BORDRO =0
group by tabA.id,tabB.MappId,bordro_installment.COLLECTION_METHOD_ID  ,
tabA.PAID_AMOUNT_IN_BODRO, tabB.TRANSACTION_AMOUNT, tabB.REMAINING_AMOUNT_TO_BE_PAID ,
ae.REFERENCE_ID ,ai.STORED_INST_AMOUNT having abs(sum(cb.AMOUNT))!=abs(tabA.PAID_AMOUNT_IN_BODRO)

    ) 
    update tableA set tableA.value1  = tableB.value2
    from DataSet ob  join AC_INSTALLMENT_TRK tableA on tableA.id =   ob.id  
    join AC_BORDRO_ALLOCATION_TRK tableB on tableB.INSTALLMENT_ID  = tableA.id  
    where  tableB.MappId  = ob.Mappid and tableA.id = ob.id
```

Please tell me what's is wrong with my query.

Comment: Please post your **actual** query instead of obfuscating it with whatever "-------some conditions-----" is meant to be.

Comment: Yes, updated with the  actual query.

Comment: Uhhh, that's a very complex query... none of us here can really help you with that unless you post a DBFiddle that reproduces the problem you're having: https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: Actually the With clause will give me Id and Mappids. I am just updating value based on those Ids in where clause.  So we dont have any issue in complex part of the query. I doudbt on the update query.

Comment: check you update statement using select whether it's returning correct result (according to your requirement) or not you need to fix WHERE/ON condition within CTE or UPDATE join.

Comment: Why do you have a `GROUP BY` and a `DISTINCT` in the same scope when you have no aggregation? That doesn't make any sense. A `GROUP BY` already causes your data to be returned in *distinct* sets, so if you are getting duplicates, it likely means your `GROUP BY` is wrong. Otherwise the `DISTINCT` is redundant and unneeded overhead. As you have no aggregation, then the `GROUP BY` doesn't belong in that scope.